# Выводит NULL в программе когда запускаю

Tags: java

Всем привет написал код который читает данные из базы данных. В моем случае имя и фамилию всех студентов. Я написал код но почему то он выводит фамилию а имя в виде "null"

```
Students : null null Falcone
Students : null null Wayne
Students : null null Parker
Students : null null Grey
Students : null null Norris
Students : null null Kent
```

Вот мой код

```
package sqltest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class SQLtest {


    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/univer?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=GMT";
    private static final String user = "root";
    private static final String password = "password";





    private static Connection con;
    private static Statement stmt;
    private static ResultSet rs;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String query = "SELECT student.id, student.name ,student.surname from student";

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                String firstName = rs.getString(2);
                String lastName = rs.getString(3);
                String count = null;
                String firstname = null;


                System.out.println("Students : " + count + " " + firstname + " " + lastName);
            }

        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try { con.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { }
            try { stmt.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { }
            try { rs.close(); } catch(SQLException se) {  }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы создаёте новую пустую переменную

```
String firstname = null; //вот здесь
```

Удалите эту переменную и используйте `firstName`

```
String firstName = rs.getString(2);
String lastName = rs.getString(3);
String count = null;

System.out.println("Students : " + count + " " + firstName + " " + lastName);
```

Comment: можете написать

Comment: код я что то не догоняю)

Comment: у вас 2 переменных, у одной большая буква N, у другой маленькая

Comment: N? там вроде же все одинаково написаны

Comment: `s/ count + " " + firstname/ count + " " + firstName/`

Comment: ладно исправил чтобы совсем понятно было

Comment: Спасибо вам большое) имя вывелось но до него null

Comment: null потому что у вас count = null

Comment: за место null что можно написать чтобы он его не выводил

Comment: это какие-то совсем школьные вопросы, например "";

Comment: Просто удалите `" + count + "`

Comment: Спасибо большое) простите я только учусь)